# Splitting project into modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've been trying to split my project into modules according to its classes/packages responsibilities. I can't seem to find any conventional architecture to guide me, though.

Basically, I have my classes segmented as follows

```
app (module)
- Application
- Activities
- Fragments
- Views
- Data
```

Where the Activities and Fragments act as controllers for the Views. What I'd like to do is to split everything into something like:

```
app (module)
- Application
- Activities
- Fragments
dependencies {
    - ui
    - data
}

ui (module)
- Views

data (module)
- Data
```

The problem is that both the app module and the data module, although very different, also depend on a same third-party library for the back-end server side. Also, the Activities and Fragments depend on the data module.

What are good practices for splitting a project into separate modules? In Android/Android Studio/Gradle, is it possible to have different modules with the same dependency? Is it possible to have two modules having each other as a dependency?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never done it before in Android, but for a Java project, I split it into multiple modules using gradle. I assume it would be similar in Android.

For common dependencies, in your top-level `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        // put common dependencies here
    }
}
```

To have modules depend on each other, in the modules `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':data')
}
```

In your `settings.gradle`, include all the different modules:

```
include 'app'
include 'data'
```